# How can I use or implement a multicolor progress circle in react native?

Tags: react-native, charts

There are multiple frameworks which provides single color progress circle component for react native, but I need to use a multicolor progress circle (like the image below). Is there any framework provides this kind of progress circle or is there any tutorial which help me to implement one?

I need progress circle like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can do use that code, it will render a multiple colors. then you can according the width to change color. the width you can change according to your buishness

```
render() {
     let borderLeftColor =  this.state.width > 0 : "green" : "white"
     let borderRightColor=  this.state.width > 25 : "yellow" : "white"
     let borderBottomColor=  this.state.width > 50 : "pink" : "white"
     let borderTopColor=  this.state.width > 75 : "blue" : "white"
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1,marginTop:50}}>
        <View style={[styles.circle,{
           borderLeftColor:borderLeftColor,
           borderRightColor:borderRightColor,
           borderBottomColor:borderBottomColor,
           borderTopColor:borderTopColor, 
           }]}/>
      </View>

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  circle:{
     width:100,
     height:100,
     borderWidth:20,
     borderRadius:50
  }
});
```

if you want to use third library, you can use [`react-native-progress`](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-progress)